# Flex: Get Resource ( image ) by it's name?

Tags: apache-flex, resources

I have checked ResourceManager, but seems like i missed something or i just checked into the wrong place.

- I have an resource ( embed image ) which i need to retrieve by it's name. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3a.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6119c-7ff0). There is an example of embedding images in resource bundle and getting it with resource manager. It looks like the following. In your resource bundle (`RegistrationForm.properties` file):

```
flag=Embed("images/unitedstates.gif")
```

Extracting image:

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [ResourceBundle("RegistrationForm")]
</fx:Metadata> 

<s:Image source="{resourceManager.getClass('RegistrationForm', 'flag')}"/>
```

Comment: emh ... there isnt some direct way to instance resources by their file name instead ? I wish to create things in pure AS3, without MXML. :|

Comment: As you can see within `source` attribute is pure ActionScript. THere is no strict MXML usage requirements in sample code above.

Comment: ... but it is only MXML, i see none AS3. hmm i am missing something.

Comment: `resourceManager.getClass('RegistrationForm', 'flag')` is AS, didn't you know?

Comment: this really doenst explain how to create this thing [ResourceBundle("RegistrationForm")] in pure AS3, neither how flag=Embed("..") will work ... I start feeling that i am inserting the resources not as i should. Currently i just drag and drop the images from some location ( like C:\x.jpg ) to my project... Is there some real resource manager, or something , and how to access it ?

Comment: I suppose you never read documentation and prefer to ask at SO first motivating people to retell it for you or open Google to find it for you. Ok. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3a.html) is the documentation about resource bundles. Read it carefully to not ask again: there is a sample how to use metadata in AS classes. And [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6119c-7ffd.html) is general documentation about it with localization etc. And take in mind using resource manager is mostly about localization.

Comment: And it is better if you narrow your current task and ask advice about the best way how to implement it. Because of your current question is about resource manager and resource bundles but I suppose they don't solve your problem. Try to explain problem itself in a separate question and maybe somebody can offer you some great solution.

Comment: so far so good. :) the things is just fine. my situation is follow - i have a very limited time to make "some peoples" mind to switch from some prety old Flash Professional to Flex for a serious project. So - time is limited, and i am trying to get the best of it :| So - i hope i am been excused about not proper asking questions maybe, but i have never worked with suchs before, which is the main gap anyway. :|

Comment: Maybe it is better just to tell them about advantages of Flex rather than trying to create project alone? :)

Comment: Yes. I told about it not once. But they prefer "eye to see, hand to touch" if you know what i mean :| ... Switching the whole development from one product to another which is completely unxplored is hard thing :E